# Convert android integer resource ID to hex/name

Tags: android, resources, icons, integer

I used `context.getApplicationInfo().icon` to get the integer resource id of the icon in my application. (ex. 2130837504) Is there a way to convert that into the name? (ex. `R.drawable.icon`)

Comment: R.drawable.icon is also an int which is defined in R.java though autogenerated. its not a string

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What purpose could it serve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your answer in [get a resource (a string) from its unique integer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694306/android-get-a-resource-a-string-from-its-unique-integer)

Please let me know if you are looking for something else!